# How to convert a list of webelement to another list in the form of string?

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
    d.get("https://bbc.com");   
    List<WebElement> lst=d.findElements(By.tagName("a"));   
    for(int k=0;k<=lst.size();k++)
        List<String> lst1=lst.add(get(k).getText());
}
```

---

my aim is to import all text formated webelement to lst1

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> lst=d.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for(WebElement e : lst){
    strings.add(e.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should create an instance of `List<String>`:

```
List<String> lst1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then just get an element (`lst.get(k).getText()`) from `lst` and add it to `lst1` in the loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); ++i) lst1.add(lst.get(i).getText());
```

---

Or use the lovely way with Stream API:

```
lst.stream().map(WebElement::getText).forEach(lst1::add);
```

Comment: after that i want to sorted the list....so i used Collections.sort(lst1);
  System.out.println(lst1); ...but it showing some error

Comment: The loop will generate a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because of the condition `k <= lst.size()`, it should be `k < lst.size()`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do the same

```
List<WebElement> lst=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
lst.forEach(variable -> strings.add(variable.getText()));
```

Arrow operator also rocks!